# How to get separate out characters from within a string

Tags: javascript

I have a string:

```
string = "abc_test_dashboard.json";
```

The value of string could vary like:

```
"tes.test.dashboard.json"
"jhgwefj-gfjh.widget.json"
```

The last "dashboard.json" and "widget.json" is static and could be either of them depending on a condition.

Basically I'm trying to identify if its "dashboard" or "widget" from the string.

I want to do stuff based on:

```
if ("dashboard.json") {//do some stuff}
else { // do something else
}
```

I also just realized that I may  have multiple files with same name, and hence I may end up getting (1), (2) suffixes i.e: `"abc_test_dashboard(1).json"`, `"abc_test_dashboard(2).json"`. is there any way to test these kind of scenarios?

Thanks

Comment: strings have two methods you can use, `indexOf` and (later browsers - but polyfill available for internet exploder) `includes` - there are other methods too - you just need to read some documentation

Comment: YOu can even use substr/substring ... so many choices

Comment: I'm not sure how indexOf would work, as the string name could be something like: "dashboard_23.widget.json" and this would end up being true, which is incorrect. can you please provide an example of how the includes() would work here? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with

```
if(string.endsWith('dashboard.json')) {

}

if(string.endsWith('widget.json')) {

}
```

Also you can use regex if you want (in case your target browsers do not support `endsWith`);

```
if (/widget\.json$/.test('widget.json')) { 

}
```

Using regex you can even extract the initial portion of the file;

```
var widgetInfo = 'asd.widget.json'.match(/^(.*)widget\.json$/)
if (widgetInfo) {
    console.log(widgetInfo[1]) // will print `asd.`
}

// similar code to check for `dashboard.json`
```

EDIT:

In the case you commented you can use the following regex; `/^(.*)widget(\(.+\))?\.json$/`. It will match strings in the forms of `randomstring.widget.json` and `randomstring.widget(1).json`, but not `randomstring.widget().json`

Comment: sorry my bad, I should have checked for various conditions before hand. I just realized that when I have multiple files with same name, I end up getting (1), (2) suffixes i.e: "abc_test_dashboard(1).json", "abc_test_dashboard(2).json" and currently the app does not care about same name strings, in that case the string.endsWith() fails for me. Any ideas how to overcome this issue? Thanks!

Comment: i tried, but it gives me  null, anything I'm missing: https://jsfiddle.net/waossyfp/2/

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind RegEx, you can use the String match() method as in the below:

```
function checkStrEnd(str) {
  if (str.match(/dashboard\.json$/)) {
    console.log('Do dashboard stuff');
  } else if (str.match(/widget\.json$/)) {
    console.log('Do widget stuff');
  } else {
    console.log('Do something else');
  }
}

checkStrEnd('tes.test.dashboard.json'); // 'Do dashboard stuff'
checkStrEnd('jhgwefj-gfjh.widget.json'); // 'Do widget stuff'
checkStrEnd('random string'); // 'Do something else'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to see if the string exists within the string

```js
let arr = ["tes.test.dashboard.json", "jhgwefj-gfjh.widget.json"]

arr.forEach(item => {
  if (item.includes('dashboard.json')) {
    console.log('dasboard')
  } else if (item.includes('widget.json')) {
    console.log('widget')
  }
})
```